# VC++, linking error with wxWidgets, x64

Tags: c++, visual-c++, 64-bit, wxwidgets, unresolved-external

I'm compiling a VC++ 10 application on Windows 7 x64 with wxWidgets 2.8. And this is the errors I have. The code is generated using wxFormBuilder.

Update: I try to run it on 32-bit machine as well, still having the same problem.

I have no idea which wxwidgets libraries I'm missing out, or what settings did I do it wrong. Tried both in Debug and Release mode.

I'd really appreciate if someone could point to some hints! Been looking at this problem for a while.

```
1>WelcomeDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class wxPoint const wxDefaultPosition" (?wxDefaultPosition@@3VwxPoint@@B)
1>ConsoleDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class wxPoint const wxDefaultPosition" (?wxDefaultPosition@@3VwxPoint@@B)
1>ControlDialog.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class wxPoint const wxDefaultPosition" (?wxDefaultPosition@@3VwxPoint@@B) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl ControlDialog::loadFile(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (?loadFile@ControlDialog@@QEAAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>WxWidgetsWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class wxPoint const wxDefaultPosition" (?wxDefaultPosition@@3VwxPoint@@B)
1>MainFrame.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class wxPoint const wxDefaultPosition" (?wxDefaultPosition@@3VwxPoint@@B)
1>MainFrame.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned __int64 const wxStringBase::npos" (?npos@wxStringBase@@2_KB) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainFrame::MainFrame(class wxWindow *,class UIApp *)" (??0MainFrame@@QEAA@PEAVwxWindow@@PEAVUIApp@@@Z)
1>UIApp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned __int64 const wxStringBase::npos" (?npos@wxStringBase@@2_KB)
1>VISUI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned __int64 const wxStringBase::npos" (?npos@wxStringBase@@2_KB)
1>WelcomeDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned __int64 const wxStringBase::npos" (?npos@wxStringBase@@2_KB)
1>ConsoleDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned __int64 const wxStringBase::npos" (?npos@wxStringBase@@2_KB)
1>ControlDialog.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned __int64 const wxStringBase::npos" (?npos@wxStringBase@@2_KB)
1>Helper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned __int64 const wxStringBase::npos" (?npos@wxStringBase@@2_KB)
1>WxWidgetsWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned __int64 const wxStringBase::npos" (?npos@wxStringBase@@2_KB)
1>MainFrame.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * const wxEmptyString" (?wxEmptyString@@3PEBDEB)
1>UIApp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * const wxEmptyString" (?wxEmptyString@@3PEBDEB)
1>VISUI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * const wxEmptyString" (?wxEmptyString@@3PEBDEB)
1>WelcomeDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * const wxEmptyString" (?wxEmptyString@@3PEBDEB)
1>ConsoleDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * const wxEmptyString" (?wxEmptyString@@3PEBDEB)
1>ControlDialog.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * const wxEmptyString" (?wxEmptyString@@3PEBDEB)
1>Helper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * const wxEmptyString" (?wxEmptyString@@3PEBDEB)
1>WxWidgetsWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * const wxEmptyString" (?wxEmptyString@@3PEBDEB)
1>ControlDialog.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class wxMBConvUTF8 & wxConvUTF8" (?wxConvUTF8@@3AEAVwxMBConvUTF8@@EA)
1>Helper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class wxMBConvUTF8 & wxConvUTF8" (?wxConvUTF8@@3AEAVwxMBConvUTF8@@EA)
1>WxWidgetsWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: static struct wxEventTable const wxGLCanvas::sm_eventTable" (?sm_eventTable@wxGLCanvas@@1UwxEventTable@@B)
1>WxWidgetsWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * const wxFrameNameStr" (?wxFrameNameStr@@3QBDB)
1>VISUI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * const wxFrameNameStr" (?wxFrameNameStr@@3QBDB)
1>WxWidgetsWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class wxPalette wxNullPalette" (?wxNullPalette@@3VwxPalette@@A)
1>WxWidgetsWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class wxCursor wxNullCursor" (?wxNullCursor@@3VwxCursor@@A)
1>WxWidgetsWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const wxEVT_NULL" (?wxEVT_NULL@@3HB)
1>WxWidgetsWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const wxEVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND" (?wxEVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND@@3HB)
1>WxWidgetsWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const wxEVT_PAINT" (?wxEVT_PAINT@@3HB)
1>WxWidgetsWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const wxEVT_SIZE" (?wxEVT_SIZE@@3HB)
1>WxWidgetsWindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const wxEVT_IDLE" (?wxEVT_IDLE@@3HB)
```

The libraries I'm linking against (64-bit wxwidgets libraries)

`wxbase28.lib
wxmsw28_core.lib
wxmsw28_richtext.lib
wxmsw28_html.lib
wxmsw28_gl.lib
wxmsw28_adv.lib
comctl32.lib
Rpcrt4.lib`

My compiling settings:

- Treat Wchat_t as built in type: Yes
- Multi-threaded Debug DLL

Comment: Have you included the corresponding libraries path in your project or make file?

Comment: @Purnima I have. I'm certain that it founds the .lib files.

Comment: [Hope this will help you](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=289136)

Comment: it's not enough to add the names to the Additional Dependencies. you also have to make sure the linker can actually find them in the appropriate folders. you should add the folders to Additional Library Directories

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution to my own problem. Just post here in case anyone faces it.

It's not about x64 or x32, neither about wxWidgets. I just need to add these 2 lines in header (before `#include <wx/wx.h>`)

```
#define __WXMSW__
#define WXUSINGDLL
```

Comment: WXUSINGDLL it is! I added it to the project defines instead of the source file because I include wx in several source files.

I am using wxWidgets 2.9.4 with their experimental binaries from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxwindows/files/2.9.4/binaries/

Answer (score 1):

How did you build wxWidgets? My understanding is that you will have to change the Visual Studio projects files distributed with wxWidgets, so that it builds in 64-bit mode. Unless you are targeting 32-bit mode. So make sure that you are targeting the same architecture with both your application and wxWidgets (i.e. both should be either 32 or 64 bit).

Also, last I looked, wxWidgets 2.8 doesn't support x64, you will need to upgrade to wxWidgets 2.9 if you want to target x64.

You can also check out the following link: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Supporting_x64_and_Win32_within_one_solution

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to convert to 2.9 (or above) and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

```
1>WelcomeDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class wxPoint const wxDefaultPosition" (?wxDefaultPosition@@3VwxPoint@@B)
```

This is an extremely strange external symbol.  What is 'class' doing there - it is a C++ keyword.  What are all the spaces doing?

My guess is that something horrible happened during compilation.  Are you certain you even submitted your source code to a C++ compiler?

Comment: Actually that code is generated by wxFormBuilder. I have no control over.

Comment: I am not familiar with wxFormBuilder.  You will have to find out how to configure the compilation step of your build, for it is there that I believe your problem lies.  Please edit your question to mention wxFormBuilder.

Comment: @ravenspoint: C++ compilers and linkers use "name mangling" to encode information about namespaces, classes and/or function parameters in the object symbol names, as in "?wxDefaultPosition@@3VwxPoint@@B" above.  The version with spaces explains the corresponding C++ source code accounting for the symbol, in this case a `const` object of `class wxPoint` called `wxDefaultPosition`.  That's all normal and correct, and not a sign of a toolchain issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problems on MSVC 2019 as described in the question when try to build from precompiled binaries downloaded from site.
When I compiled from source from `...\build\msw\wx_vc12.sln` with "Release" option (NOT "Release DLL", but "Release") and get "vc_x64_lib" folder everything works. In my case no needs specify `#define __WXMSW__` and `#define WXUSINGDLL`, just check you build with `Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)`