# wxWidgets Visual Studio 2015 Link Errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, wxwidgets

I am trying to run the minimal wxWidgets sample using Visual Studio Community 2015 under Windows 10. wxWidgets version is 3.1.0.

I have compiled wxWidgets using the following command:

```
nmake -f makefile.vc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 MONOLITHIC=1 BUILD=release
```

The compilation of wxWidgets was successful with above-mentioned command.

The [minimal wxWidgets example](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_helloworld.html) compiles well but I get the following link errors in the *release* version (havent tried debug yet):

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void (__cdecl* wxTheAssertHandler)(class wxString const &,int,class wxString const &,class wxString const &,class wxString const &)" (?wxTheAssertHandler@@3P6AXABVwxString@@H000@ZA)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class wxEventTypeTag<class wxCommandEvent> const wxEVT_MENU" (?wxEVT_MENU@@3V?$wxEventTypeTag@VwxCommandEvent@@@@B)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: static class wxAppConsole * (__cdecl* wxAppConsoleBase::ms_appInitFn)(void)" (?ms_appInitFn@wxAppConsoleBase@@1P6APAVwxAppConsole@@XZA)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * const wxFrameNameStr" (?wxFrameNameStr@@3QBDB)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: static class wxAppConsole * wxAppConsoleBase::ms_appInstance" (?ms_appInstance@wxAppConsoleBase@@1PAVwxAppConsole@@A)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class wxMBConv * wxConvLibcPtr" (?wxConvLibcPtr@@3PAVwxMBConv@@A)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * const wxLOG_COMPONENT" (?wxLOG_COMPONENT@@3PBDB)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned int const wxString::npos" (?npos@wxString@@2IB)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class wxSize const wxDefaultSize" (?wxDefaultSize@@3VwxSize@@B)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "bool wxTrapInAssert" (?wxTrapInAssert@@3_NA)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "wchar_t const * const wxEmptyString" (?wxEmptyString@@3PB_WB)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static bool wxLog::ms_doLog" (?ms_doLog@wxLog@@0_NA)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * const wxStatusLineNameStr" (?wxStatusLineNameStr@@3QBDB)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static unsigned long wxThread::ms_idMainThread" (?ms_idMainThread@wxThread@@0KA)
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class wxPoint const wxDefaultPosition" (?wxDefaultPosition@@3VwxPoint@@B)
```

I have the following Preprocessor definitions:`WIN32;_UNICODE;__WXMSW__;UNICODE`

The whole linker flags: `/OUT:"C:\Users\gb\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\wxWidgetsDeneme\Release\wxWidgetsDeneme.exe" /MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\gb\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\wxWidgetsDeneme\Release\wxWidgetsDeneme.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "wxmsw31u.lib" "wxmsw31u_gl.lib" "wxexpat.lib" "wxjpeg.lib" "wxpng.lib" "wxscintilla.lib" "wxtiff.lib" "wxzlib.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /OPT:REF /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"C:\Users\gb\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\wxWidgetsDeneme\Release\wxWidgetsDeneme.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Release\wxWidgetsDeneme.exe.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\gb\Downloads\wxWidgets-3.1.0\lib\vc_dll" /TLBID:1`

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973571/vc-linking-error-with-wxwidgets-x64

Comment: It is *kinda* similar since in the link you posted, the question does not mention how wxWidgets was compiled and I think it is the key, such as whether the compilation was static vs dynamic.

Comment: here https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Troubleshooting_building_wxWidgets_using_Microsoft_VC#Unresolved_External_Symbol_Linker_Errors is saying that if you receive `LNK2001 and LN2019` error it means your linking is wrong, it says `find a sample wxWidgets application which uses the same functions that are not correctly linked in your application`

Comment: @BladeMight: Not sure how your point is related to the question.

Comment: @macroland, the best way to start is to compile and run 'minimal' sample provided with the library, i.e. wxWidget/samples/minimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would not think it would have been this simple: just a preprocessor definition was missing: `WXUSINGDLL`

[In the documentation](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Guide) it mentions:  *WXUSINGDLL:If you're compiling using DLLs instead of a static build* and since I am using `nmake -f makefile.vc SHARED=1 ...`.

I am just curious now: Why wxWidgets runs without any problem using `gcc` even if `WXUSINGDLL` was missing from the preprocessor definition.

Comment: Recent versions of binutils (i.e. linker used by gcc) implement "auto-importing", so they will find symbols in a DLL even if you don't use the correct import declarations. It's still better to use them, even with gcc, though.

Comment: @VZ. Thanks, everything worked well under Eclipse-CDT where my compiler was `gcc`. I tried to replicate the settings similar to Eclipse and got the link errors in VS. I did not know `gcc` was automatically importing the symbols in DLL. Learned something new...

Answer (score 2):

Compiling wxWidgets with Visual Studio is explained in the file `docs/msw/install.txt` that ships with wxWidgets distribution.

In short there are two ways:

- a) From the IDE using the provided project files.
- b) From command line using the provided makefiles

For b) it's just nmake /f makefile.vc with some flags of the kind of libraries you wish. for example `nmake /f makefile.vc BUILD=release SHARED=1` will build several `.dll` files that may be used by your app, and they will not contain any debug symbols.

Your compiling command lacks makefile.vc. In this file some flags like WXUSINGDLL are defined or not depending on your command flags.

When compiling your app, you must use the same flags as those used for wxWidgets compiling.

Comment: Thanks and sorry I forgot to write makefile.vc to the question, although I have compiled with it. I have edited the question and the answer to improve them.